# how to pass email address to retrieve data from data base in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I'm developing a project for a student administrative system in asp.net mvc4.

I'm trying to retrieve data from the database - the selection operation is done using a field called **emailID** - the actual data like email address"john@gmail.com". The **emailID** is the id which has primary key constraint;

While clicking on Action.url in the View it passes the urls like this (Get: method)

```
localhost:1262/User/EditUserProfile/john%40gmail.com
```

and it returns HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found;

If I pass the email address as "john@gmail.com" directly to selectMethod(emailID); it will return proper result as I want;

Routing the url is the problem - I think - so please if any of you can help me to solve this issue ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a **/** at the end `localhost:1262/User/EditUserProfile/john%40gmail.com/`

Comment: it is manual work; how can do this  ..localhost:1262/User/EditUserProfile/john%40gmail.com/.. from routing itself.. plz

Comment: if you are building the url with jquery you can add the trailing / as part of the build